# How to query data from one table which isn't available on another table, given that, the same data should not be in the same table as well?

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

Imagine I have two tables, User and Registrations table. They both contain the column 'secret_token'. I would like to fetch all results from the registrations table against the secret token which:

1. is unregistered in the registrations table (tinyint column 'is_complete' is there for this matter)
2. must not be present against any user in the user table.

Demo:

### User

```
id name secret_token
1  jack 13drasdadad
2  john as5a6889sda
```

### Registrations

```
id secret_token is_complete
1  13drasdadad  1           // note this exists in user table (shouldn't be in the result)
2  1agf803sdd2  0
3  gh994hkakll  0
4  gzgfg03zzd2  0
5  gh994hkakll  1           // note this token exists twice (where in one row is_complete is 1). Hence should be excluded from results.
```

The sample output I'm looking for would be:

```
id secret_token is_complete
2  1agf803sdd2  0
4  gzgfg03zzd2  0
```

Till now, the query I developed is:

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM
    registration t
        INNER JOIN
    registration t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.is_complete = false
        LEFT JOIN
    user u ON t.secret_token = u.secret_token
WHERE
    u.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

P.S. Looking for a solution through joins. Subquery can easily solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired results you can use following query, there is no need to join again your `registration` table just do a `left join` with user and in `where` clause return records where `u.id IS NULL`

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM
    registration t
LEFT JOIN `user` u ON t.secret_token = u.secret_token
WHERE t.is_complete = 0 AND u.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/653aa7/1)

**Edit** The same secret token should never have is_complete = 1 for it to appear in the result set

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM
    registration t
LEFT JOIN registration t1 ON(t.secret_token = t1.secret_token
                            AND t1.is_complete = 1
                            )
LEFT JOIN `user` u ON t.secret_token = u.secret_token 
 WHERE t1.secret_token IS NULL AND u.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/460bce/6)

Comment: This does not serve my purpose. Please note the updates in the registration table. The same secret token should never have is_complete = 1 for it to appear in the result set.

Comment: @ShahedBinSatter i have updated my answer for above criteria

Comment: Thanks, the updated query totally works. I just needed to invert the way i kept thinking...was a great lesson on how joins work!